# How to count minimum number of pairs satisfying divisibility condition.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Consider the pair of numbers $(x_1, y_1),\, (x_2, y_2),\, (x_3, y_3), \dots$ and so on, each $x$ and $y$ is a natural number. Then what should be the least number of such pairs required, so that we are guaranteed have some pairs (at least $2$ pairs) that satisfy $X_m-X_n$ divisible by $7$ and $Y_m-Y_n$ is divisible by $3$?

Please suggest a way to solve questions like this.

Comment: please don't down vote it.I really thought, and not able to get the way.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and show your working in future :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to impose a uniqueness constraint on all $x$ and $y$ 
(i.e. $\forall i,j\; x_i = x_j \implies i=j$ and $\forall i,j\; y_i = y_j \implies i=j$) otherwise there is no minimum.

You can answer this question by considering the number of differences between $x$ values you can make that *aren't* divisible by 7. Obviously there are only 6 differences unique mod 7 that aren't divisible by 7 the question then becomes how quickly are we guaranteed to hit all of these differences.

Lemma: Prove that given 3 unique integers x,y,z their pairwise differences cannot all be equal and non-zero mod 7.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $x-y\equiv z-y \equiv x-z \equiv a \not\equiv 0 \mod 7$ then:
Since $x-y\equiv a\mod 7$ and $y-z\equiv a\mod 7$ we have $$(x-y)-z\equiv (y-z)-z \implies x-z\equiv 2(y-z) \implies a\equiv 2a$$ which is not true for any non-zero $a$ so we have a contradiction and our proof.

From here you can argue that given $n$ integers you have to have at least $n-1$ equivalence classes of 7 represented in their pairwise differences and deal with 3 similarly but I leave that to you.